# Install PyQt5 5.14.1 on Linux

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtchart

```
pip3 install PyQt5
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/fb/eb51731f2dc7c22d8e1a63ba88fb702727b324c6352183a32f27f73b8116/PyQt5-5.14.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-b2zw891b/PyQt5/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-b2zw891b/PyQt5/
```

Then I downloaded zip folder from https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5 and run:

```
python3 configure.py --qmake /home/oo/Qt/5.14.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake
make
sudo make install
```

Successful

```
>>> import PyQt5
>>> import PyQt5.QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'
>>>
```

So I installed

```
pip3 install PyQt5.sip
pip3 install sip
```

Successful

but still getting same error `No module named 'PyQt5.sip'` for `import PyQt5.QtCore`

also tried PyQtChart but still error

```
pip3 install PyQtChart
Collecting PyQtChart
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/35/4f6328db9a31e2776cdcd82ef7688994c11e265649f503858f1913444ba9/PyQtChart-5.14.0-5.14.0-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting PyQt5>=5.14 (from PyQtChart)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/fb/eb51731f2dc7c22d8e1a63ba88fb702727b324c6352183a32f27f73b8116/PyQt5-5.14.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-gzep4mr7/PyQt5/setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-gzep4mr7/PyQt5/
```

I also downloaded zip folder from https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtchart/download and run:

```
python3 configure.py --qmake /home/oo/Qt/5.14.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake
Error: Unable to import PyQt5.QtCore. Make sure PyQt5 is installed.
```

QT screenshot::
[image]

My end goal is to run candlestick chart using pyqt5.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pyqt5 pyqtchart
[sudo] password for oo:  
The directory '/home/oo/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/oo/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pyqtchart in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.7 in /home/oo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyqtchart)
```

but still getting same error:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt5
>>> import PyQt5.QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'
>>>
```

Comment: elementary OS 5.1 Hera

Comment: Update the question, I am still getting same error

Comment: I also removed all PYQT packages from `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/` and then installed `pyqt5 pyqtchart pyqt5.sip sip` but still for `import PyQt5.QtCore
` error is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I think the initial `pip install` woes were due to PyQt5 switching to the manylinux2014 platform tag for the latest release (see the wheels on PyPI for [5.14.1](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/5.14.1/#files) vs [5.14.0](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/5.14.0/#files)). Only pip versions >= 19.3 recognize this platform tag ([ref](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux/issues/338)), so if you happen to have an older version of pip, it would instead try to install from source.

Two easy options (to avoid the source install):

- Update pip to the latest via `pip3 install --upgrade pip`
- Install the previous release, which used manylinux1 (`pip3 install pyqt5==5.14.0`)

Comment: Installing 5.14.0 fixed it for me

Comment: pip3 upgrade to 21.0.1 worked on WSL running Pengwin Enterprise Scientific Linux.

Comment: Yeah, upgrading stuff fixes 90 percent of the problems !

Comment: Upgrading pip worked, but then I missed `libxcb-util.so.1` (Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.)  Installing the previous release (5.14.0) let me run the app.  Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

It seems that there is a bug in the latest version of PyQt5 to pypi so I installed a version 5.14:

```
sudo apt-get update && \
    sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install \
    -y --no-install-recommends \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools

sudo python3 -m pip install pyqt5==5.14 pyqtchart==5.14
```

Copy the example of [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50548931/6622587) in the main.py and then run:

```
python3 main.py
```

I recommend you search the folders and files generated by your failed attempts and delete them.

<sub>For my test I used the following [Dockerfile](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/59711301)</sub>

Comment: Why did you use sudo to run pytho3 -m pip?

Answer (score 10):

I also had the same issue installing `PyQt5` (while trying to install `ReText`).

On `Ubuntu 18.04` with `Python 3.6.9` and `Pip 9.0.1`, I was able to pip install `PyQt5` with these steps:

```
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip3 install pyqt5 --only-binary pyqt5
```

That was enough to make pip download the `PyQt5-5.14.0-5.14.0-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` binary wheel (that doesn't need/use the `setup.py`) instead of building from the source tarball.

According to https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/#files, there are other binary wheels too, so hopefully that'll cover most platform needs.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is very difficult to install PyQt5 on Debian or Ubuntu Linux distro.
I was able to install it for python3 on my system running Debian 10 buster (stable). 
I installed it with the apt package manager.

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

Comment: The only option that worked for me, all pip installs of the 5.14.x and 5.15 versions failed because of syntax errors in the requirements or obscure files missing.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too. It's because your `pip` is on older version and you should update it by using the below commands:

```
pip3 install setuptools wheel
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install --user pyqt5
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who do not desperatly need 5.14, 5.12 can be a solution. This worked for me:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pyqt5==5.12 pyqtchart==5.12
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Question showed, you are downloading `tar.zip` file not `wheel`. Installing QT with pip is only allowed with `wheel`. Choose the version that has wheel file in PyPI homepage and matches to your Python version.

Answer (score 0):

I had to build right version of sip from source in order to build desired version of PyQt5 from source and then I also got following error:

```
No module named 'PyQt5.sip'
```

and then

```
python3 -m pip install PyQt5.sip
```

solved the issue