# PyQt5 dependency in a module on Debian

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5, setuptools

I have a Python module with a __main__ that uses PyQt5. I've installed PyQt5 on a Debian Buster box:

```
apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

The `__main__` program runs as expected if I execute

```
python3 mymodule/__main__.py
```

from the  source directory. Now I've installed the module into python:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

That worked. The setup.py lists a dependency on pyqt5:

```
setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=['PyQt5'],
    entry_points={"gui_scripts": ["mymodule = mymodule.__main__:main"]},
```

Setup created a script `/usr/local/bin/mymodule`. When I run that, I get an error message:

> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'PyQt5' distribution was not found and is required by mymodule

What am I missing?

EDIT: tried installing pyqt5 via pip, got the following error:

```
seva@sandbox:~$ sudo pip3 install pyqt5
Collecting pyqt5
Using cached  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/fb/eb51731f2dc7c22d8e1a63ba88fb702727b324c6352183a32f27f73b8116/PyQt5-5.14.1.tar.gz
Installing build dependencies ... done
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 447, in open
    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-install-26kj5hrc/pyqt5/setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-26kj5hrc/pyqt5/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS-level package managers are designed to be consistent within itself. But they aren't designed to interoperate with language package managers. `apt-get`-installed `python3-pyqt5` could be recognized by other Debian packages but not by `pip`/`setuptools`.

So either you convert your package to `.deb` (using [`stdeb`](https://pypi.org/project/stdeb/), for example), set dependency to `python3-pyqt5` and install it with `apt`/`apt-get`/`dpkg`. Or you install everything using `pip`:

```
pip install pyqt5
pip install .  # to install your package
```

If your dependencies are properly declared in the package the latter command should be enough — `pip` will run the former itself.

PS. Also please consider `virtualenv` to separate `pip`-installed packages from system-installed. `virtualenv` itself could be system-installed or user-installed:

```
apt install python3-virtualenv
```

or

```
pip install [--user] virtualenv
```

Comment: I'd rather go with pip - I'm aiming for cross platform here. But, `sudo pip install pyqt5` errored out on me, see the edit...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59712128/7976758 `sudo pip install pyqt5==5.14`

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm facing another issue, but at least PyQt5 resolves :)

Comment: You can ask many questions, not necessary to pack all into the one. :-)

Comment: Not my first day at SO :)