# File in current folder not found when installed with pip

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Python module with an entry point (same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086660/pyqt5-dependency-in-a-module-on-debian)). The `__main__` file imports another:

```
from myfile import MyClass
```

`myfile.py` is a file in the same folder, `mymodule`. It contains the class called `MyClass`. This works under regular Python, if I run `python3 __main__.py`.

Now, I've installed `mymodule` as a module with `sudo pip3 install .` on MacOS X (EDIT: same error on Linux). When I run `mymodule` from the command line, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` for myfile:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/valekseyev/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/mymodule", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('mymodule==0.50', 'gui_scripts', 'mymodule')()
File "/Users/valekseyev/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/Users/valekseyev/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2793, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/Users/valekseyev/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2411, in load
return self.resolve()
File "/Users/valekseyev/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2417, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
File "/Users/valekseyev/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mymodule/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
from myfile import MyClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myfile'
```

The file `myfile.py` is present alongside `__main__.py` under `/Users/valekseyev/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mymodule/`, I've checked. There's an `__init__.py` in the folder, too, it's blank. The folder is listed under `packages` in `setup.py`.

What's going on please?

EDIT: looking at Python modules out there, they import other files from the same folder with the following syntax:

```
from .myfile import MyClass
```

If I try that, the regular Python runs break:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Any way around that, maybe?

Comment: If the directory is named `mymodule`, that is your package name. Try `from mymodule.myfile import MyClass`.

Comment: Won't that break compatibility with regular runs, not as an installed module?

Comment: If it's meant to be a module it should always be ran as a module IMO. You can use `setup.py develop` for local runs.

Answer (score 0):

Found one way around. I've prepended the file names with . in the import lines, created a file one level up (on the same level as `setup.py`) that would treat the `mymodule` folder as a package:

```
from mymodule.__main__ import main
main()
```

and I can run that. There's yet another issue I'm facing (library modules take precedence over patched versions), but not this one :)