# Python3 on ARM Linux Debian Buster - PyQt5 not works properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, arm, debian-buster

I'm trying to install Qt5 for Python on ARM Linux (Debian Buster 10). The version of Python is 3.7.3.
I've installed Qt5 using apt with command:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default pyqt5-dev pyqt5-dev-tools
```

When try to entering on Python3, if I using declaration:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
```

the import works fine (I don't get any error).

But when I continue with:

```
app = QApplication([])
```

I got the error:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 148 (Unknown), sequence: 181, resource id: 0, major code: 140 (Unknown), minor code: 20
```

If I try to install PyQt5 from pip, I got this

```
sudo pip3 install pyqt5
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/fb/eb51731f2dc7c22d8e1a63ba88fb702727b324c6352183a32f27f73b8116/PyQt5-5.14.1.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-install-_70atgk5/pyqt5/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-_70atgk5/pyqt5/
```

Sorry, but I cannot understand where the problem is.
Thanks.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59797479/6622587

Comment: Thanks for supply @eyllanesc. However, I've tried to install pyqt5==5.14.0, but I get another error,  `Invalid requirement: 'sip >=5.0.1 <6'`, but I still have sip installed, version 5.1.1...

Comment: For now, I've resolved using `sudo apt-get install qt5-default pyqt5-dev pyqt5-dev-tools`, but when I start an application I got this warning: `qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 148 (Unknown), sequence: 181, resource id: 0, major code: 140 (Unknown), minor code: 20`