# python egg-info e 1

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to upgrade some python module on sraspberry pi 4 running noobs and when I tried to upgrade PyQt5 it gave the fallowing error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-install-9x3nwc_3/PyQt5/setup.py'
    
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-9x3nwc_3/PyQt5/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install PyQt5 5.14.1 on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59711301/install-pyqt5-5-14-1-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Run this command :

```
pip install PyQt5==5.14
```

Thanks

Comment: when i ran that i got this:
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-mhosj7h8 --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --extra-index-url https://www.piwheels.org/simple -- "sip >=5.0.1 <6" "PyQt-builder >=1.1.0, <2"" failed with error code 1 in None