# Installing PyQt5 in pyenv created virtual envirionment

Tags: python, pyqt5, apple-m1, python-venv, pyvenv

I'm currently struggling to install a python package in a virtual environment. The set-up is the following: I have an M1 mac and with it, I have the system python installations located in `/usr/bin/python` (v 2.7.18) and `usr/bin/python3` (v 3.8.9). Since I don't really like messing with these, I have installed `pyenv` and `pyenv-virtualenv` over `brew`. I installed Python 3.10.1 and created a virtual environment, let's call it `test`. I also added the following lines to `.zshrc`

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi

alias brew='env PATH="${PATH//$(pyenv root)\/shims:/}" brew'
PATH=$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH
```

(Most of this was done by following the explanations on the [github page of pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)).

I'm now trying to install some packages in `test`. `numpy, scipy`, etc worked perfectly but when I try to install `PyQt5` with `pip` I get an error.

```
❯ pip install PyQt5
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/UserName/.pyenv/versions/3.10.1/envs/simpy/bin/python3.10 /Users/UserName/.pyenv/versions/3.10.1/envs/simpy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/yk/q1gxptj56gj5n3jt8l48xj580000gn/T/tmp2ofsepfy
       cwd: /private/var/folders/yk/q1gxptj56gj5n3jt8l48xj580000gn/T/pip-install-5rev2dd7/pyqt5_3892c9f35c2f41a186bcd36237d536d7
  Complete output (29 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/UserName/.pyenv/versions/3.10.1/envs/simpy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
  AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/UserName/.pyenv/versions/3.10.1/envs/simpy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Users/UserName/.pyenv/versions/3.10.1/envs/simpy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/Users/UserName/.pyenv/versions/3.10.1/envs/simpy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "/private/var/folders/yk/q1gxptj56gj5n3jt8l48xj580000gn/T/pip-build-env-vyb7aqa6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
      project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
    File "/private/var/folders/yk/q1gxptj56gj5n3jt8l48xj580000gn/T/pip-build-env-vyb7aqa6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
      project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
    File "/private/var/folders/yk/q1gxptj56gj5n3jt8l48xj580000gn/T/pip-build-env-vyb7aqa6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 587, in setup
      self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "/private/var/folders/yk/q1gxptj56gj5n3jt8l48xj580000gn/T/pip-install-5rev2dd7/pyqt5_3892c9f35c2f41a186bcd36237d536d7/project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "/private/var/folders/yk/q1gxptj56gj5n3jt8l48xj580000gn/T/pip-build-env-vyb7aqa6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "/private/var/folders/yk/q1gxptj56gj5n3jt8l48xj580000gn/T/pip-build-env-vyb7aqa6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 234, in apply_user_defaults
      self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "/private/var/folders/yk/q1gxptj56gj5n3jt8l48xj580000gn/T/pip-build-env-vyb7aqa6/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
      raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
  sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/27/fd81188a35f37be9b3b4c2db1654d9439d1418823916fe702ac3658c9c41/PyQt5-5.15.6.tar.gz#sha256=80343bcab95ffba619f2ed2467fd828ffeb0a251ad7225be5fc06dcc333af452 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/UserName/.pyenv/versions/3.10.1/envs/simpy/bin/python3.10 /Users/UserName/.pyenv/versions/3.10.1/envs/simpy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/yk/q1gxptj56gj5n3jt8l48xj580000gn/T/tmp2ofsepfy Check the logs for full command output.
```

What exactly is going on here? Is this related to the m1 chip or the set-up of the virtual environment? How can I fix this?

---

On the suggestion of @pedro_bb7 I downgraded Python to 3.9.9 (since `PyQt5` is not yet ready for Python 3.10.0) and also tried installing an older versions (`5.14.1/2/, 5.15.0/1/2/3/4/5/6`) of `PyQt5` over the command

```
❯ pip install PyQt5==5.14.0
Collecting PyQt5==5.14.0
  Using cached PyQt5-5.14.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
ERROR: PyQt5==5.14.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/5b/e760ec4f868cb77cee45b4554bf15d3fe6972176e89c4e3faac941213694/PyQt5-5.14.0.tar.gz#sha256=0145a6b7de15756366decb736c349a0cb510d706c83fda5b8cd9e0557bc1da72 has a pyproject.toml file that does not comply with PEP 518: 'build-system.requires' contains an invalid requirement: 'sip >=5.0.1 <6'
```

As you can see, still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to upgrade pip to the latest, as suggested:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67606704/11381650

**EDIT:** it's not yet supported for `Python 3.10` as you can see:

https://github.com/altendky/pyqt-tools/issues/98

and try different versions of `PyQt`, could you try `5.14.0` for Python 3.9?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59797479/11381650

Comment: Already done and does not work. Pip is at version 21.3.1

Comment: How about PyQt version? Maybe you need to specify one that works for the Python version you are using..

Comment: I just tried it with Python 3.9.9 and I get the same error...

Comment: added more one step to my answer

Comment: Still no luck.. The error message is: `❯ pip install PyQt5==5.14.0
Collecting PyQt5==5.14.0
  Using cached PyQt5-5.14.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
ERROR: PyQt5==5.14.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/5b/e760ec4f868cb77cee45b4554bf15d3fe6972176e89c4e3faac941213694/PyQt5-5.14.0.tar.gz#sha256=0145a6b7de15756366decb736c349a0cb510d706c83fda5b8cd9e0557bc1da72 has a pyproject.toml file that does not comply with PEP 518: 'build-system.requires' contains an invalid requirement: 'sip >=5.0.1 <6'`

Comment: Are you trying to install it on a Raspberry? Anyways, try `5.14.1`

Comment: Nope, macOS... Newst version.

Comment: Tried 5.14.1/2/, 5.15.0/1/2/3/4/5/6 and all don't work. The error message can be found [here](https://codedump.xyz/ruby/YdwWK7N_1bylw7zw).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240919/discussion-between-pedro-bb7-and-sito).

Comment: Is there any update? Wondering if you were able to resolve this as I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @morejanus Nope, not really. You can install `PyQt5` over `homebrew` and should be able to use it with `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`. But I still can't get it to run in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Use rosetta terminal, install pyqt5

Youtube link to open rosetta terminal on Mac m1
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9W8rTTE1WEA

And then use pip to install under your virtual enviorment

```
 pip install PyQt5
```

---

Method 2: Running under pyqt6

Like LemurPwned said in [How can I run pyqt5 on my Mac with M1chip (ppc64el architecture)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901162/how-can-i-run-pyqt5-on-my-mac-with-m1chip-ppc64el-architecture/67812605#67812605)

pyqt6 is now easily installable via pip on M1/M2 Macs

You can install that via

```
pip install PyQt6
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).